# Calcule $\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}$ where $b=b(x(t),y(t))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider
$$\begin{cases}x=x(t)=x_2+t(x_3-x_2)\\y=y(t)=y_2+t(y_3-y_2)\end{cases}\quad t\in[0,1] \tag{$*$}$$

and $b(t)=t(1-t)$, where $x_2,x_3,y_2$ and $y_3$ are known constants.

Calculate $\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}$ as a function of $t$.

---

**My idea** is: from $(*)$ we obtain:

$$t=\dfrac{x-x_2}{x_3-x_3} \text{ and } t=\dfrac{y-y_2}{y_3-y_3}$$

and then

**(a)** $b(x,y)=\dfrac{x-x_2}{x_3-x_3}\left(1-\dfrac{x-x_2}{x_3-x_3}\right){\color{red}\Rightarrow\boxed{\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}\neq 0}}$

and

**(b)** $b(x,y)=\dfrac{y-y_2}{y_3-y_3}\left(1-\dfrac{y-y_2}{y_3-y_3}\right){\color{red}\Rightarrow\boxed{\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}= 0}}$

But this way we obtain two diferents expresions for $\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}$.

Why I'm wrong? Which is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you've done everything correctly, both versions should give you the same result, there is a relationship between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: but with (b) we obtain $\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}=0$ (because not depend on $x$), and for (a): $\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}\neq 0$ (because is not a constant in $x$)
 that makes sense?

Comment: You can write $y$ as a function of $x$: $$y=\left(\frac{x-x_2}{x_3-x_2}\right)(y_3-y_2)+y_2$$ then $\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense at all. The given information doesn't define $b$ uniquely as a function of $x$ and $y$, so what on earth does $\partial b/\partial x$ mean here?

Comment: why not @HansLundmark? $t$ is related whith the natural parametrization of the line between both points, so for each $(x,y)$ on the line exists a unique $t$...

May you give me an example of suitable function to understand what you say?

Comment: Yes, and for each $t$ there is a unique $(x,y)$ on the line, so the formula $b(t)=t(1-t)$ says what $b$ are *for those points*. But in order to compute $\partial b/\partial x$, you need a function $b(x,y)$ defined *on the whole plane*, not just on the line. (Or at least defined in a neighbourhood of the line, to be pedantic.)

Comment: thaks @HansLundmark, now I see.